# why is string response from server changing when I am using alamofire in ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to retrieve a string from server using alamofire in an ios app but the problem is that the response is changing as it is prefixing ever entity with "\" character. here is my code:

```
func getInformation()
    {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let parameters: Parameters = ["SchoolCode": "TCenYrhWUQH7kKLVZ1FQgQ==", "FacultyInfoCode":"cFl9ivLKKKk5PgH4tbi/Gg=="]
        Alamofire.request("http://epunjabschool.gov.in/webservice/staffwebservice.asmx/StaffDetails", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString{ response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            if let JsON = response.result.value {
                var string = JsON
                if let idx = string.lastIndex(of:"[") {
                      var index1=idx+1
                    var index2 = string.lastIndex(of:"]")!-1
                    var substring = string.substring(from:index1,to:index2)
                        if let dataFromString = substring.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                            let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                      //      for i in 0..<json.count
                         //   {
                                var js=json[0]
                                if(self.defaults.string(forKey: "status") == "hr")
                                {
                                     self.district.text=js["Name"].stringValue
                                     self.school.text=js["UserMaster_DisplayName"].stringValue
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   self.district.text=js["Faculty_Name"].stringValue
                                    self.school.text="dfjdnfj"

                                }
                           // }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

here is the response which i am getting when running the same service from broswer:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"FacultyInfo_Code":"107406","Faculty_Name":"Vipul bansal","Father_Name":"Vijay kumar","DOB":"21-Sep-1986","Gender":"Male","CasteCategory_Name":"GENERAL","Religion_Name":"HINDU","MaritalStatus_Name":"UnMarried","Disability":"No Disability","Qualification_Acad":"+2","Qualification_Prof":"MSC(IT)","ComputerTypingKnowledge_Name":"Both","Cur_Address":"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, FARIDKOT, Punjab","Per_Address":"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, S.A.S. NAGAR, Punjab","Disatance":"27.00","MobileNo":"8427010890","EmailID":"vipulbansal59@yahoo.in"}]~[{"FacultyInfo_Code":"107406","Faculty_Name":"Vipul bansal","Father_Name":"Vijay kumar","DOB":"21-Sep-1986","Gender":"Male","ServiceType":"Regular","StaffType":"Teaching","AppointmentUnder":"PICTES","Current_DesignationName":"Computer Faculty","Subject_Taught":"COMPUTER SCIENCE","DateOfJoining":"18-Sep-2009","Joining_Present_Desination":"29-Oct-2010","DISTRICT_CODE":"5","DISTRICT_NAME":"FARIDKOT","School_Name":"GHS DHURKOT","EDU_BLOCK_NAME":"FARIDKOT-03","udise_code":"03130103102","RecordType":"S","Mobile_No":"8427010890","Email_Id":"vipulbansal59@yahoo.in"}]
</string>
```

here is the reponse from alamofire:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">[{\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"Faculty_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-1986\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"CasteCategory_Name\":\"GENERAL\",\"Religion_Name\":\"HINDU\",\"MaritalStatus_Name\":\"UnMarried\",\"Disability\":\"No Disability\",\"Qualification_Acad\":\"+2\",\"Qualification_Prof\":\"MSC(IT)\",\"ComputerTypingKnowledge_Name\":\"Both\",\"Cur_Address\":\"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, FARIDKOT, Punjab\",\"Per_Address\":\"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, S.A.S. NAGAR, Punjab\",\"Disatance\":\"27.00\",\"MobileNo\":\"8427010890\",\"EmailID\":\"vipulbansal59@yahoo.in\"}]~[{\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"Faculty_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-1986\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"ServiceType\":\"Regular\",\"StaffType\":\"Teaching\",\"AppointmentUnder\":\"PICTES\",\"Current_DesignationName\":\"Computer Faculty\",\"Subject_Taught\":\"COMPUTER SCIENCE\",\"DateOfJoining\":\"18-Sep-2009\",\"Joining_Present_Desination\":\"29-Oct-"...
```

As it can be seen, the problem is the "\" extra character in the alamofire response making it impossible for me to parse the json data. Why is the data changing in alamofire response?

Comment: its not the correct way parse the data. You must use xml parser then convert the data to json. It'll fail if you get an array inside your json.

Comment: @rajvir Singh : Response you have shared which you are getting that is not actually json response , which you shared is sample response @ API page. Can u please share exact reponse which you got from server using code. Then i wiil clear your remianing doubts.

Comment: {\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"Faculty_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-1986\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"CasteCategory_Name\":\"GENERAL\",\"Religion_Name\":\"HINDU\",\"MaritalStatus_Name\":\"UnMarried\",\"Disability\":\"NoDisability\",\"Qualification_Acad\":\"+2\",\"Qualification_Prof\":\"MSC(IT)\",\"ComputerTypingKnowledge_Name\":\"Both\",\"Cur_Address\":\"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, FARIDKOT, Pkotkapura, S.A.S. NAGAR, Punjab\",\"Disatance\":\"27.00\",\"MobileNo\":\"\",\"EmailID\":\"vipulbansal59@yahoo.in\"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire is not changing the data, this is just the way the console prints it out. The easiest way to handle this would be to simply couple ObjectMapper along with Alamofire to parse this response. OR you could use the following :

```
func getInformation()
{
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let parameters: Parameters = ["SchoolCode": "TCenYrhWUQH7kKLVZ1FQgQ==", "FacultyInfoCode":"cFl9ivLKKKk5PgH4tbi/Gg=="]
    Alamofire.request("http://epunjabschool.gov.in/webservice/staffwebservice.asmx/StaffDetails", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON{ response in

switch response.result {
case .success:
    let json = response.result.value
case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: i want to retrieve the string data and pass two parameters. Kindly tell me how to do it. Your code isnt changing anything. it is the same that i used bro.

Comment: Thanks Jaison Titus

Answer (score 0):

This is `JSON` formatted `String`:

```
{\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"Faculty_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-1986\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"CasteCategory_Name\":\"GENERAL\",\"Religion_Name\":\"HINDU\",\"MaritalStatus_Name\":\"UnMarried\",\"Disability\":\"No Disability\",\"Qualification_Acad\":\"+2\",\"Qualification_Prof\":\"MSC(IT)\",\"ComputerTypingKnowledge_Name\":\"Both\",\"Cur_Address\":\"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, FARIDKOT, Punjab\",\"Per_Address\":\"sikkhan wala road, channy street, house no.2, kotkapura, S.A.S. NAGAR, Punjab\",\"Disatance\":\"27.00\",\"MobileNo\":\"8427010890\",\"EmailID\":\"vipulbansal59@yahoo.in\"}]~[{\"FacultyInfo_Code\":\"107406\",\"Faculty_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-1986\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"ServiceType\":\"Regular\",\"StaffType\":\"Teaching\",\"AppointmentUnder\":\"PICTES\",\"Current_DesignationName\":\"Computer Faculty\",\"Subject_Taught\":\"COMPUTER SCIENCE\",\"DateOfJoining\":\"18-Sep-2009\"....
```

If you will parse it then you will be able to see it without \"

Parse it using `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
func getInformation()
    {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let parameters: Parameters = ["SchoolCode": "TCenYrhWUQH7kKLVZ1FQgQ==", "FacultyInfoCode":"cFl9ivLKKKk5PgH4tbi/Gg=="]
        Alamofire.request("http://epunjabschool.gov.in/webservice/staffwebservice.asmx/StaffDetails", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString{ response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            //UPdated Code
            do {
                let responseObject = try     NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data, options: []) as!  [String:AnyObject]

//Use responseObject as NSdictonary to get your data

    } catch let error as NSError {
 print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

            if let JsON = response.result.value {
                var string = JsON
                if let idx = string.lastIndex(of:"[") {
                      var index1=idx+1
                    var index2 = string.lastIndex(of:"]")!-1
                    var substring = string.substring(from:index1,to:index2)
                        if let dataFromString = substring.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                            let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                      //      for i in 0..<json.count
                         //   {
                                var js=json[0]
                                if(self.defaults.string(forKey: "status") == "hr")
                                {
                                     self.district.text=js["Name"].stringValue
                                     self.school.text=js["UserMaster_DisplayName"].stringValue
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   self.district.text=js["Faculty_Name"].stringValue
                                    self.school.text="dfjdnfj"

                                }
                           // }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I need to use it as a string and then retreive the json from it. I tried to insert your statament but it is asking me to use ; to seperate multiple statements. I tried this   string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: ""). But it aint working . all i need is to eliminate all the occurences of \ character. Pls tell me how to do that?

Comment: Just updated answer. mistakenly i have given you objective C code before.

Comment: I think you are making  your logic complex. As per my understanding you are simply getting JSON response from server and want to get data from some keys. So what i have provided you is the code to parse JSON string and it will return a dictionary from which you can get your data.

Comment: it is not giving me direct json formatted string. I need to parse the string first. Kindly tell me how to remove this \ character from a string

Comment: pls tell me how to remove \ character from the response. i tried this string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") but its not working