# How to remove \ character from a string in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

My string is contained in a variable named str. This code isnt working :

```
  str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

Comment: Are you sure the \ character exists in your string, as opposed to just some character that is, itself, escaped when you print/examine the value of the variable? Show us precisely how you concluded there was a \ character present...

Comment: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">[{\"Info_Code\":\"107406\",\"_Name\":\"Vipul bansal\",\"Father_Name\":\"Vijay kumar\",\"DOB\":\"21-Sep-] response retrieved from server

Comment: @rajvirsingh This string you mentioned doesn't contain any "\" actually!

Comment: I think here you are using XML Parsing so you need to use here XML Parser that is the Better way to get data behalf remove tags or "\", and i am going to suggest use SWXMLHash or link: - https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash use this beautiful library for getting values from server.

Comment: Most likely these escape characters are merely a result of how you printed the XML string. E.g. because the string contains quotation mark, it's likely just escaping that quotation mark when it prints it ... the backslash is not really there in your string, just in the printed output. This looks like it's ready to be passed to your XML parser (e.g. [`XMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmlparser)).

Comment: No I am using alamofire and the string contains a "\" charcter when retrieved from server

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355457/why-is-string-response-from-server-changing-when-i-am-using-alamofire-in-ios-app

Comment: Please write your question here properly then able to help you.

Comment: but it is a json formatted string not an xml formatted string u are right that \ charcter doesnt exist in the actual string but it is generated in the retrieved response

Comment: anand refer to this link mate: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355457/why-is-string-response-from-server-changing-when-i-am-using-alamofire-in-ios-app

Answer (score 4):

this line remove \ from string

```
 str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The thing was that it didn't contain any \ character. Its just the property of swift that it will always return such a string on console. The workaround is to j-son parse it.